# Physical proximity of Disaster Recovery site

Tags: disaster-recovery

We are researching a hosting company to hold our DR site.  The problem is that they are in neighboring states.  One host is in Herndon, Virginia.  The other is in Charlotte, NC.

Are these too close together for a primary and DR?

Does anyone know of best practices documentation that can help guide us?

Comment: This can't be answered without a copy of your risk assessment and disaster recovery objectives.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of a disaster you're planning for.

- A storm that knocks out the city's power?
- Tornado?
- Fire?

For these they are probably far enough apart that it won't matter.

- Nuclear strike?
- Regional data outage?

For these maybe not.

What are the odds that any particular disaster will take out both facilities? Would you bet on those odds?

Comment: Regional data outage or large weather event are my biggest concerns.  On top of those concerns I need to be able to defend the position.  I was hoping there were guidlines (government or otherwise) somewhere to help guide this.

Comment: Think of a DR facility as an insurance policy. The more you spend the more coverage you get.

Answer (score 1):

That really is depending on your DR tech's limits. 400 miles (I hope GMaps isn't fooling me) is anything but near.